# VB.NET - MySQL Howto terminate query from MySQL server when application force close

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am developing a client server program with VB.NET and MySQL as the database backend with huge records on each table and do some heavy join queries

And now i am having problem when a client run heavy join query and it will takes several mins to complete and suddenly the client force close the apps using Windows' secret weapon `ctrl + alt + del`, however the query still run in server. This query sometime caused other queries are being queued.

Is there any way i can prevent this issue? Is it from the code itself or from MySQL's server?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to manage this from the server as the client is detached. In MySQL you can use KILL to remove a process.

There is a suggestion here how you could write a query to generate a KILL list, so if you can identify the queries in question then you could write something to clear up your orphans.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/21/mass-killing-of-mysql-connections/

There is also a tool - pt-kill - available as part of this toolkit which might be of use to you. https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/index.html

The toolkit is free open source software.

Disclosure: I am from Percona.

Comment: I can detect those orphan queries using tool provided by navicat and kill them. But how the big enterprise prevent those orphan queries? Is there someone that always monitoring all queries in server? Or there is something we can do with the program  code to prevent this kind of issue? Lets say for example we can prevent user to terminate the program before the queries complete (this is just example)

Comment: You would probably struggle to stop a client from terminating - a determined user would just turn their workstation off. The most likely solution would be to have a job scheduled to clean up the orphan processes, by calling a command line tool and interrogating the output. Or maybe looking at ways to prevent the locks from occurring in the app, there's a lot of advice written on that subject.

Comment: Fair comment bummi, I removed an unnecessary reference to Percona and added my disclosure.